# Unable to use type Instance from aws-sdk-v2 golang module

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-go

I am importing the following `go` module:

```golang
import "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/ec2"
```

I want to write a simple function that iterates over the instance tags so I am doing the following

```golang
func getInstanceDescription(instance *ec2.Instance) string {
    for _, tag := range instance.Tags {
        if *tag.Key == "Name" || *tag.Key == "name" {
            return *tag.Value
        }
    }
    return *instance.InstanceId
}
```

However, despite the fact that [Instance](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/ec2/types#Instance) is a type of this package, compiler complains

> undefined: ec2.Instance compiler(UndeclaredImportedName)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As you can see, the Instance is not in the `ec2` package; it's in the `types` package. You should use `instance *types.Instance` and `import github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/ec2/types`. Did this help you to resolve the issue?

Comment: thanks, that was it, if you want proceed adding as an answer so that I mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `Instance` struct wrongly. As the `Instance` struct is not in `ec2` package, it is in the `types` sub package.

You should use as

```
import "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/ec2/types"


func getInstanceDescription(instance *types.Instance) string {
    for _, tag := range instance.Tags {
        if *tag.Key == "Name" || *tag.Key == "name" {
            return *tag.Value
        }
    }
    return *instance.InstanceId
}
```